# How to use react-router-dom nested routes using outlet in separate file

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Here is the link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-nested-routes-z9hy45

I'm using react-router-dom and define my routes in separate file, I want to use nested routes with outlet for protected routes

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

    <Route element={<ProtectedLayout />}>
      <Route path="/user" element={<User />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

This works exactly how I want, but I want to declare this logic in routes.js file and just use

```
const routes = useRoutes(publicRoutes)
const protectedRoutes = useRoutes(privateRoutes)
return (
  <div>
    {router}
    // So what I want is to protectedRoutes be wrapped by ProtectedLayout somehow in routes.js
    {protectedRoutes}
  </div>
```

Comment: All you've really done is to define two sets of independent routes. I don't see any nested routes in any of the routes configurations, nor any descendent routes. Can you [edit] to include an actual [mcve] for what you are trying to do, and clarify what the goal is you are wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @DrewReese I edited my question, hope this made it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the public/private routes to JSX, and import & render these in `App`.

Example:

routes.js

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./components/Home";
import { Login } from "./components/Login";
import { User } from "./components/User";

export const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />
  }
].map((props) => <Route {...props} />);

export const privateRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/user",
    element: <User />
  }
].map((props) => <Route {...props} />);
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProtectedLayout } from "./components/ProtectedLayout";
import { privateRoutes, publicRoutes } from "./routes";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        {publicRoutes}
        <Route element={<ProtectedLayout />}>
          {privateRoutes}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could also instead use a Data router and pass the routes in the configuration object.

routes.js

```
import { Home } from "./components/Home";
import { Login } from "./components/Login";
import { User } from "./components/User";

export const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />
  }
];

export const privateRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/user",
    element: <User />
  }
];
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProtectedLayout } from "./components/ProtectedLayout";
import { privateRoutes, publicRoutes } from "./routes";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...publicRoutes,
  {
    element: <ProtectedLayout />,
    children: [...privateRoutes]
  }
])

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}
```